# Why is the Kafka 0.10 kafka-console-consumer.sh missing the --group argument?

Tags: apache-kafka

How do  you indicate which group you want to consume from?

The command does not know what "--group" means and the help doesn't show any argument that seems to be for the group you want to consume from.

```
# where is the "--group mygroup" arg below?
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytopic
```

Comment: as side note, because you are using kafka 0.10 I would use the new consumer and not the old one, so without the --zookeeper option but using --bootstrap-server with the broker address:port list.

Comment: Thanks, I am doing just that to completely get rid of client use of scala and zookeeper access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `--consumer-property group.id=XXXX` to specify the group ID.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a consumer properties file, like the one provided with Kafka (`config/consumer.properties`) and specify the `group.id` in there. The properties file is passed in the command line using the `--consumer.config` argument:

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic mytopic --consumer.config config/consumer.properties
```